# Remove duplicates in list of lists where an item in each list is ignored when determining duplicity

Tags: python, performance, vectorization

I have `lines_list_copy` of the form:

```
[['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2'], ... ]
```

I needed to remove all duplicate entries where `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` are identical. So note that I don't care about what value `e` has. So for example, If `lines_list_copy = [['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e2']]` we have three values that are the same, namely `lines_list_copy[0]`, `lines_list_copy[2]` and `lines_list_copy[3]` and any 2 of them need to be deleted which will give us the value of `lines_list`. At the end deleting any two results in a valid outputs for `lines_list`

`lines_list_copy` has lengths typically exceeding 200000 and realistically will eventually exceed 500000 with the amount of data we are collecting. Thus I needed a way to remove duplicates fast. I found a way to efficiently remove all duplicates, but the method would take `e` into account and thus wouldn't give me what I need. Therefore, I delete all the `e` values in each list first like so:

```
for x in lines_list_copy:
  del x[cfg.TEXT_LOC_COL]
lines_list_copy = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in lines_list_copy)]
```

After which I have `lines_list_copy` as I need it. All I need to do is re-add any one of the `e` values for each list. My double for loop is admittedly naive and more so that I didn't think it would bring my program to a crawl.

```
    for line_copy_ind in range(len(lines_list_copy)):
        for line_ind in range(len(lines_list)):
            if lines_list_copy[line_copy_ind][cfg.TIME_COL] == lines_list[line_ind][cfg.TIME_COL] and \
                    len(lines_list_copy[line_copy_ind]) == 4:
                lines_list_copy[line_copy_ind].append(lines_list[line_ind][cfg.TEXT_LOC_COL])
    lines_list = lines_list_copy
```

I looked into vectorizing and using filter but just cant seem to reverse engineer solutions to other problems and make them work for my problem of adding `e` back on the end of each list in `lines_list_copy`. Maybe there's an elegant way for me to instead not delete the `e` column and still remove duplicates efficiently without considering the `e` values?

Comment: Would you always have 5 elements in every element of that lists of list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Maybe there's an elegant way for me to instead not delete the e column and still remove duplicates efficiently without considering the e values?

Your `set`-based approach almost works, and should be more efficient than the nested loops. Try storing only the first 4 items in the set, as opposed to the entire row:

```
def unique_by_first_n(n, coll):
    seen = set()
    for item in coll:
        compare = tuple(item[:n])    # Keep only the first `n` elements in the set
        if compare not in seen:
            seen.add(compare)
            yield item

filtered_list = list(unique_by_first_n(4, lines_list_copy))
```

Here I've adapted your `set` approach to consider only the first `n` items when comparing rows, but then to `yield` the entire row if it hasn't been seen yet. `yield` could also be replaced by first defining an empty output list and `append`ing to it, like in your second solution.

We get around the `del e` problem by not deleting anything, just returning all of the rows where the first `n` columns have not been seen yet.

Comment: I fell off my chair in laughter... it's so fast